# Consistant Phyics with cannon-es.js

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

i have a game of dominos built with three.js and cannon-es.js. I am struggling to create consistent gameplay despite resetting all cannon bodies velocity, angularVelocity, force and torque after each playthtough. I run at 30 cycles per second and all positions are reset as well. Any pointers on how to tighten up the physics so every game plays the same way? maybe a random variable Iam not aware of or temporarily setting all bodies mass to 0?